# Tic Tac Toe game in c++, issue with play again function

Tags: c++

I'm a very beginner and I have an issue with this askPlayAgain function, made for a Tic Tac Toe game. When I finish the first game, the function works. It asks me if I want to play again or not. But after the second game ends, the program ends, telling me "player x won", without asking the yes or no question. Can you help me with this issue?

I will insert only the specific part of this project, because the site doesn't allow me to insert it all. If necessary, I will insert other parts of the project.

```
void askPlayAgain(string firstPlayer, string secondPlayer)
{

    char option;
    do {
        cout << "Play again? Y for yes, N for no" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        break;
    } while (option != 'Y' || option != 'y' || option != 'N' || option != 'n');

    if (option == 'Y' || option == 'y') {
        initializeTable();
        startGame(firstPlayer, secondPlayer);
    }
    else {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (option != 'Y' || option != 'y' || option != 'N' || option != 'n');` The condition will always be true option can't be 'Y', 'y','N' and 'n' at the same time.

Comment: You should convert the character to upper case or lower case before comparing.  It will reduce the quantity of comparisons.  See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.

Comment: Your condition for looping is "`option` is different from at least one of these characters", so the condition for stopping is "`option` is the same as all of these characters".

Comment: It seems your problem is around where and how you call this function. It currently always should check for input (in a broken way but it should)

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that it's because `askPlayAgain` is only called once in the entire program.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about your `while` condition--even just those for yes:

```
while (option != 'Y' || option != 'y')
```

In what case can this be false? With an OR, that'll only happen if both conditions are false. However, it's not possible for a character to both be 'Y' AND be 'y'.

Instead, you want AND's here:

```
while (option != 'Y' && option != 'y' && option != 'N' && option != 'n');
```

Or even cleaner could be:

```
std::string good_inputs = "YyNn";
do {
    // ...
} while (good_inputs.find(option) == std::string::npos);
```

However, **none of that ever gets run**! You have a `break` in your while loop, so the condition is never checked. I'm not sure what your thought was there, but that should be removed.

Comment: See also: `std::tolower`, `std::toupper` and `std::transform`.

Answer (score 0):

You placed break statement after getting input(option) from user so what is the
purpose of several conditions in while.
**When a break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next statement following the loop** ...

```
 do {
        cout << "Play again? Y for yes, N for no" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        break; 
    } while (option != 'Y' || option != 'y' || option != 'N' || option != 'n');
```

My suggested code:

````
{

char option;

        cout << "Play again? Y for yes, N for no" << endl;
        cin >> option;

    while(option != 'Y' && option != y && 'y' && option != 'N' && option != 'n')
{

cout << "invalid input enter again" << endl;
cin >> option;
// this loop run until user give right input
}
    if (option == 'Y' || option == 'y') {
        initializeTable();
        startGame(firstPlayer, secondPlayer);
    }
    else if(option == 'N' || option == 'n'){
        exit(0);
    }

}```
````